# File Access in Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, fileinfo

I have a Windows Service which has 8 timers running parallel (elapsed time = 10 sec) and each timer is performing some activity and logs the `write_time` when it enters the timer and `end_time` when it exits the timer and this happens for all the timers.
I have a ASP.net application which reads the logs for the `write_time` and `end_time` for each timer and displays it on a grid.

Commonly I get an error for file operations which causes my timer to stop. The code block is below.

Write_time

```cs
        FileInfo file = null;
        StreamWriter write = null;
        try
        {
            file = new FileInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SupportFilePath"].ToString() + processName + "_Log.txt");

            write = new StreamWriter(file.FullName);
            write.Write(string.Empty);

            write.Write(processName + "_" + time + " at: _" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
            write.Close();
            write.Dispose();

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            _errorMonitoringEngine.ErrorInfo(" ", ex.StackTrace.ToString(), ex.Message, "Email Notification Engine", "WriteTimeProcess2");
        }
```

I get maximun times the exception `The process cannot access the file`. Please advise how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely two or more threads are trying to write to the same file at the same time.

Create an instance of an `object` somewhere in your class and `lock` it whenever you need to write to the file.

```
public class Example
{

  // ...

  // Depending on whether there are one or many instances of 
  // this class determines whether this needs to be static 
  // or not. If it needs to be static, use a static constructor.
  private object syncObject = new object();

  // ...

  void WriteToFile()
  {
    lock (syncObject)
    {
       // Do file IO
       // Now no two threads will attempt to access the file at the same time
    }
  }

  // ...

}
```

It would also be wise to wrap the `StreamWriter` in a `using` statement.